# jQuery unload event

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to determine if the user clicked on a link, the forward or back button or entered a new URL in the address bar, in the following event?

```
$(window).unload(function(e) {
    // here
}
```

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers can't distinguish between tab close, browser close, refresh, new address entered.  All will trigger an unload event - the DOM is unloaded.  Unfortunately there's no data passed to the unload event handler to distinguish between the different causes.

You could possibly do something with the mouse position - determine if the pointer is at the middle-top (for address bar), or right/left top for close.  However its not a great solution as different browsers have their buttons in different positions, and Mac/PC have close buttons on opposite sides.